# One shared android database with all devices using my app

Tags: android

I am new at android development,i have an idea to develop an application and i want to know how to do to create an app that have one database shared with all devices that can use my app).

The database can be manipulated from all apps installed in different devices and users may access to data or modifying it.

The data must be quicly synchronized to have updated information .
I am now using ormlite but i guess it be a local database.

Can you give me some guidance to solve my probleme ?

Thank's
Riden

Comment: build client and server arch

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service which will access a common database and host it on a server. From all your clients you should access the service for each database operation.

If you want a cached system, then you should take care of cache on the client side(android).

If you want more accessibility, then create lots of servers on different locations, then make clients access nearby server. Then make all servers synchronize time to time.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer,i understand from your solution its to create external BDD like mysql and duplicate the bdd into two servers to have high availability of data with using a system that synchronized data between them. can you give me some advice the data must be updated at real time ? because information can be deprecated if the synchronization is to late.

Comment: you can check these links. http://aciddrop.com/2008/01/10/step-by-step-how-to-setup-mysql-database-replication/     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html